# Bind and trigger an event in jQuery pattern

Tags: design-patterns, javascript, jquery

Commonly I bind an event with jQuery and then call it immediately afterward, such as when I set up positioning or visibility of some elements and whatnot.

```
$('#myElement').on('click', function () {
    $('#myOtherElement').css('color', 'red');
}).click();
```

This works, but the pattern is a bit ugly, especially if my first selector finds multiple elements.  Then the event is triggered multiple times, once for each element the first selector finds.  I end up doing this instead:

```
$('.lots-of-elements').on('click', function () {
    $('#myOtherElement').css('color', 'red');
}).first().click();
```

Again, this works, but it's not my favorite.  Is there a better pattern to use?

I know I can do something like:

```
function onClick() {
    $('#myOtherElement').css('color', 'red');
};

$('.lots-of-elements').on('click', onClick);
onClick();
```

But that's even more verbose.

Comment: I think this is just you being vain, the first two examples are perfectly fine

Comment: Yes and no.  On the one hand, it's mostly wanting syntactic sugar.  On the other, suppose I had multiple `onClick` handlers, ones my class doesn't know about.  That's not the case yet, but theoretically, it could be.  I'd have to pull my code into a new function, add the handler, and then call the function, rather than using the `.click()` call.  It gets more tedius.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you want to use a click event and then click it right away. Can't you just put the css editing in the main scope?

As to your question, you can also create a jQuery function like this:

```
$.fn.extend({
    clickColor: function(element, color) {
        $(this).on('click', function() {
            $(element).css('color', color);
        });
        return $(this);
    }
});
```

Put it in a seperate file and keep your main file clean with only:

```
$('#clicker').clickColor('#other', 'red').click();
$('.clicker').clickColor('.another', '#00FF00').first().click();
```

Have a look at the [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/damagex/vuje4jkb/1/).

Ofcourse you can also put the `.first()` and `.click()` inside the function if that's what you like.

Then have a look at this [**DEMO 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/damagex/vuje4jkb/2/)

Comment: The css was just a silly example.  A real example would be like having a button that hides a div and shows another (toggles).  When I use asp.net's UpdatePanel, the originally shown and hidden divs revert.  So, I track the state, and if the user was on the originally hidden div, I trigger the click event to toggle them back to the way the user had seen before.  Hope that wasn't too poorly worded.